# Keeping a table fixed to the bottom of the viewable page but scroll within that table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have created a site to load content dynamically with javascript. I have a table that I would like to be "stapled" at the bottom of the page as I scroll the main page. But I also need this table to scroll as well, as content will exceed the browser's viewable area both horizontally and vertically.

I have tried this CSS to make it work:

```
#comparison_table {
  overflow: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 99%;  /* Not 100% so as to not prompt the body-wide scroll bars */ 
  height: 15%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

"Absolute" works great for position, until I need the main body of my page to scroll down. Then the table moves up and off the page.

"Fixed" works great as it stays right there at the bottom of the browser viewing area. However, a problem arises where the table can not be scrolled vertically. (Haven't managed to test it horizontally yet.)

So if I have enough content to exceed the 15% height in #comparison_table, I can't scroll to anything that's been cut off using position:fixed. Using position:absolute, then my table doesn't stay at the bottom of the page as I scroll.

What I'm looking for ultimately is the best of both worlds: Fixed and Absolute combined in some way. I haven't found a trick to doing that.

Comment: Wrapping a table in a `<div>` while applying a positioning to that div and an overflow rule to the table doesn't work?

Comment: @tomasbedrich Not when I was experimenting with the position property. I am applying that CSS to a div tag. I had some trouble with using overflow on the table where the scrollbars would be off the page.

I did find a solution that I'll have as a separate answer. More of a work around, or a better approach I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

```
#comparison_table{
overflow:scroll;
position:fixed;
top:85%;
width:99%; <!-- Not 100% so as to not prompt the body-wide scroll bars-->
bottom:0%;
height:15%;
background-color:yellow;
}
#big_table{
height:80%;
position:fixed;
bottom:15%;
top:5%;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

After messing with a bunch of settings, I thought about defining a position for not just the "hovering table" that I wanted, but also the "background table". Breaking the page into two scrollable sections works. I don't know if there's redundant code/properties in there by defining top and bottom along with height or not, but this is the working code I could come up with.

I am still curious if anyone might know of an alternative way that might more explicitly answer the question I had.